# Проблемы с копией сайта на поддомене modx

Tags: modx

Полностью скопировал сайт на поддомен poddomen.site.ru на том же хостинге в соседнюю папку.

Когда я изменяю шаблоны/сниппеты и т.д. на поддомене в менеджере основного сайта так же вносятся изменения. В обратную сторону так же. Как быть?

Например, сейчас я изменил и сохранил шаблон главной страницы на поддомене, на основном домене в **менеджере** изменения появились, но отображение страницы не поменялось. Если я нажму сохранить в основном сайте, то и отображение поменяется.

Answer (score 0):

Так они у вас одну и ту же базу используют, либо для нового сайта префикс добавьте, либо новую базу. Да и вообще файлы конфигураций подправьте